# Problem with model, view and controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I do a hello world very easy, now I want to catch data of a class and I can't do it, when I compile the project all perfect and when I run the project show me a error: Estado HTTP 404, and I don´t know how to fix the problem, help please.

my controller is welcomeController

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
   List usuarios = catalogFacadeImpl.getUserList();
   logger.info("Returning hello view with " + usuarios);
   return new ModelAndView("welcome", "usuarios", usuarios);
```

my model is branch_try_htmlModulo-servlet.xml

```
<bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController"/>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
        <props>
             <prop key="/welcome.htm">branch_try_htmlModulo</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="beerListController" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController">
    <property name="catalogFacadeImpl" ref="catalogFacadeTarget"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

my view is welcome.jsp

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello :: Spring Application</title></head>
    <body>
     <table border="0">
       <c:forEach items="${usuarios}" var="usuario">
        <tr>
             <td><c:out value="${usuario.user_name}"/></td>
        </tr>
         </c:forEach>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

and my web.xml is

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>branch_try_htmlModulo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>branch_try_htmlModulo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: i think This code could be the problem 


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>




<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

Answer (score 2):

The entire Controller class hierarchy is deprecated.  The preferred usage of Spring MVC is to use @Controller-annotated classes.

Before you go too far down this road, you might want to read [this example](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/16).

Answer (score 0):

try changing your config to this and report if you are still having the issue...

```
<bean id="welcomeController" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController"/>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
        <props>
             <prop key="/welcome.htm">welcomeController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```